# Consequence of limit notation

Tags: calculus

I am going through Calculus introduction book by Spivak and in the Limits chapter to show the flexibility of limit notation it's asked to prove the equivalence of

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$

and
$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a + h)$

I started off with the definition:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=m$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\ | f(x) - m| < \epsilon$ there's $\delta$ such that for all x if $\ | f(x) - m| < \epsilon$ then $\ | x - a | < \delta$

In our case,

$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$ plug in $\ |h-0| = |h + a - a | = |(h+a)-a| <\delta$
then
$\lim_{h+a\to a}f(a+h)$ but variable $\ h+a$ in $\ f(h+a)$ can be replaced by any variable, e.g. x, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is equivalent to $\lim_{h+a\to a}f(a+h)$

Is this proof convincing enough?

Comment: No, it’s not. You have mixed up the definition of limit and used informal / non-standard notation with “$\lim_{h + a → a}$” (or is that something Spivak does)?

Comment: Ordering messed up badly. Correct version is, for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that (for all $x$, if $|x -a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.)